# Illegal Characters in Path While Installing Module

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, powershell-v4.0

In Powershell 4, I'm attempting to install the GoogleCloud module.

I use the command:

```
Install-Module GoogleCloud
```

It fails with:

```
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Illegal characters in path.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\PSModule.psm1:1417 char:21
+             $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestModuleManifestCommand,Microso
   ft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

**I've tried:**

- switching Set-Location to a simple path, i.e. C:\jason
- switching the Env:path to a simple lath, i.e. C:\jason\

Comment: Please share output from `(Get-Module PowerShellGet).Version.ToString()`. Maybe that `Update-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force` could help?

Comment: Update-Module : Module 'PowerShellGet' was not installed by using Install-Module, so it cannot be updated.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (PowerShellGet:String) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ModuleNotInstalledUsingInstallModuleCmdlet,Update-Module

Comment: (Get-Module PowerShellGet).Version.ToString()
1.0.0.1

Comment: `Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force` and then  restart PowerShell session (should install version `2.0.4`).